# Django tutorial, How can I send multiple arguments?

Tags: django, django-views

I know something like this has been asked before but I never seen any answer that I can understand or that works. But I am very new on Django so maybe I could have missed it. But there must be an easy answer to my question.
I am following the tutorial for Django and at section 4 they use the httpresponseredirect to go to next page after posting a form.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

The views page function looks like this:

```
def detail(request, question_id):
```

My question is: How can I send more parameters to the function?

I tried this now:

```
 urls.py
 path('<int:question_id>/result/<int:qid>/<str:aa>/', views.result, name='result'),


 views.py
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('bsapp:result', kwargs = dict(qid = question.id, xx = aa)))

 The function
def result(request, qid, xx):
```

Gives this: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'result' with keyword arguments '{'qid': 3, 'xx': '6'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['bsapp/(?P[0-9]+)/result/(?P[0-9]+)/(?P[^/]+)/$']

Answer (score 1):

This is what I had to do:

```
 xx="EXTRA ARGUMENT"
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('bsapp:result', args=(question.id, xx,)))

 path('<int:question_id>/<str:xx>/result/', views.result, name='result'),  


 def result(request, question_id, xx):
```

Thanks for your help, I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

You use kwargs rather than args where kwargs is a dictionary where the keys match the parameters in the url dispatcher - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#example

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/', views.page),
    path('blog/<slug:slug>/page/<int:num>/', views.slug_page, name="slug_page"),
    path('blog/page<int:num>/', views.page),
]

# View (in blog/views.py)
def slug_page(request, slug, num=1):
    # Do stuff here

    return redirect(reverse("slug_page", kwargs=dict(slug="example", num=2))
    ...
```

Comment: In your example it looks like the arguments are part of the path, which they not are. It is some text I want to display on next page. Or am I getting it wrong? Lets asume I would like to send just two words "HELLO" and "GOODBYE" . How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can add as many parameters as you like, just make sure your url accepts the parameter.

Ex:

urls.py

```
path('detail/<int:first_arg>/<int:second_arg>/', views.section, name='article-section'),
```

views.py

```
def detail(request, first_arg, second_arg):
```

Comment: The arguments I want to send should not be a part of the path, just text I want to display on next page.

Comment: Better to use sessions or cookies in that case.